# ¿Cómo obtener una letra según su posición en el abecedario?

Tags: php, php7

Necesito obtener una letra del abecedario a partir de una posición. Por ejemplo, si paso un 2, que me devuelva 'B', si paso un 4, que me devuelva 'D'.

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido sin tenerme que crear un array con todas las letras es sumarle 64 al número que paso y obtener el valor ASCII de este código con la función `chr`.

Sería algo así:

```
$numero = 3;
$letra = chr($numero + 64);
```

La variable `$letra` en este caso valdría 'C'.

El problema es que lo veo un poco bruto;

¿Alguien sabe si hay otra forma hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

> EDIT: Solo necesitaría letras del abecedario inglés.

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner en práctica tu idea? Prueba a hacer el código, si tienes algún problema, o no te convence, ya lo compartes, pero al menos muestra lo que has intentado. Gracias.

Comment: La solución que propones, ¿Por qué no? No lo veo tan mal, te creas una función en que a partir de un valor dado, le sumas 65 y obtienes el valor que es del código ASCII. No lo veo tan mal, serían pocas lineas de código y más "limpio" que no un diccionario

Comment: ¿Debe contar con la Ñ, CH, etc?

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que necesites usaría una cosa u otra. ¿Vas a contemplar alfabetos de diferentes idiomas? Entonces un array con el abecedario de cada idioma. ¿Vas a usar el abecedario plano sin localismos? Entonces **ASCII**, mucho más directo. ¿Necesitas el abecedario del castellano por lo que tienes que contemplar la **Ñ**? Entonces de nuevo un **array**, ya que la **Ñ** es un caracter no consecutivo en **ASCII**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considero que tienes que usar un array, por un motivo muy simple: **la función tiene que ser *null safe***, o sea, tiene que controlar si el valor valor que se le pide está entre las letras del alfabeto, de lo contrario el código daría error.

Una forma de hacerlo sería con `range`, que te va a generar de forma automática un array implícito.

Por ejemplo:

Vamos a verlo en una función:

```
function getByPosition($index){
    #Crea un array con las letras de la A a la Z
    $alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
    #Seteamos la posición restando 1 porque los índices comienzan en 0
    $pos=$index-1;
    #Retornamos la letra, o NULL, si $index desborda el array
    #Para evitar que true sea tratado como índice 1, controlamos con is_bool también
    return ( !empty($alphabet[$pos]) && !is_bool($index) ) ? $alphabet[$pos] : NULL ;
}
```

Vamos a someterla a prueba de varios modos:

```
var_dump( getByPosition(2) );
var_dump( getByPosition(1000) );
var_dump( getByPosition('l') );
var_dump( getByPosition(null) );
var_dump( getByPosition(false) );
var_dump( getByPosition('juanito el caminador') );
var_dump( getByPosition(5) );
var_dump( getByPosition(true) );
```

**Salidas:**

```
string(1) "B"
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
string(1) "E"
NULL
```

Según el contexto, la función se puede trabajar para devolver el caracter en mayúscula o minúscula según un parámetro, etc. Eso lo dejo a tu cuidado.